# Javascript: Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects, then get another objects information within that same Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an object array like this:

```
var test_data = [    
                    {
                        "id" : "Test01", //Has to be a string form ID
                        "test_info"  : "This is the test information",
                        "test_score" : 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : "Test02", //Has to be a string form ID
                        "test_info"  : "This is the test information",
                        "test_score" : 2
                    }
```

I will have a variable as follows: E.g. `var data = "Test01"`

I am wondering is it possible to use that variable to search for the object by its `id` and return the entire object (to be stored in another variable if possible).

and then

to access that object and get the `test_info` information returned?

To simplify, I want to be able to search `test_data` for an object with an `"id"` matching for example `"Test01"`. Then once that object is found in the array get the `"test_info"` information for example `"This is the test information"` from the object and store it as a string in a variable.

If possible I would appreciate any help on the matter!!

**EDIT:**
@dave your answer works perfectly as follows:

```
test_data.getTestInfo = (id) => test_data.find(t => t.id ===id).test_info;
let info = test_data.getTestInfo('Test01');
console.log(info);
```

***But***
The `"id"`matching for example `"Test01"` will be coming from a variable like `li_test = $(this).text();` but it wont work the same as it does if you use `"Test01"`.

How it should work:

```
var li_test = $(this).text();
test_data.getTestInfo = (id) => test_data.find(t => t.id ===id).test_info;
let info = test_data.getTestInfo(li_test);
console.log(info);
```

but the above code snippet returns an error - *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test_info' of undefined*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to something like this:

```js
var test_data = [{
    "id" : "Test01", //Has to be a string form ID
    "test_info"  : "This is the test information",
    "test_score" : 1
},
{
    "id" : "Test02", //Has to be a string form ID
    "test_info"  : "This is the test information",
    "test_score" : 2
}];


test_data.getTestInfo = (id) => test_data.find(t => t.id === id).test_info;


$('button').on('click', function() {
    let id = $(this).text();
    let info = test_data.getTestInfo(id);
    console.log(info);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Test01</button>
```

Comment: That works great until the moment I try bring in where you have `'Test01'` a variable as follows `var li_test = $(this).text();` the variable is taking in the name of a Test ID when a link is clicked and comes back fine as just the var but the moment its tried to bring into your answer above, it returns as follows **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test_info' of undefined**

Comment: ive tried using `var li_test = JSON.stringify($(this).text());` and it still doesn't work

Comment: @Jay1995 sounds like you need to expand your question with some more details

Comment: @solarshado do you get what id like now? sorry for not explaining it better!!

Comment: @dave thank you, I got it working. The problem was the variable was being stored with double quotes either side so just had to remove them and works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

stringToFind is your string

and

returnedObject is your matched Object.

```js
var stringToFind = "Test01";

var test_data = [{
    "id" : "Test01",
    "test_info"  : "This is the test information",
    "test_score" : 1
},
{
    "id" : "Test02",
    "test_info"  : "This is the test information",
    "test_score" : 2
}];

test_data.getObjectFromID = (id) => test_data.find( target => target.id === id );

var returnedObject = test_data.getObjectFromID(stringToFind);

console.log(returnedObject);
```

Comment: the `var stringToFind = $(this).text();`will be represented like this...this is also returning the entire object once searched instead of searching by `id` and returning just the `test_info` data which should be "This is the test information"

Comment: Can you console.log( $(this).text() ). What does it log?